# How can I pass the Id from a View to the Create method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, master-detail

I have created a master-details CRUD. My Details.cshtml looks like this:

```
@model TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel
<dt class="col-sm-2">
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarHeader.ListaOtf)
</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-10">
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaBarHeader.ListaOtf)
</dd>
(...)
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarBody.BarTelegramaFk.NrTg)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarBody.BarTelegramaFk.Continut1Tg)
            </th>
(...)
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.taBarBody)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BarTelegramaFk.NrTg)
        </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BarTelegramaFk.Continut1Tg)
            </td>
(...)
                <td>
                    <a asp-controller="BodyTelegrama" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a>
                </td>
```

So, in the Details.cshtml for a particular ID I can see the records of TaBarBody. There is a relationship one-to-many between TaBarHeader and TaBarBody.

When I create a new TaBarBody, I want to be created under that particular TaBarHeader_Id.

**Controller**:

```
public IActionResult Create(HeaderTelegramaViewModel headerTelegramaViewModel, BodyTelegramaViewModel bodyTelegramaViewModel)
        {
            TaBarBody taBarBody = new TaBarBody();
            taBarBody.BarHeaderFk = new TaBarHeader();
            taBarBody.BarHeaderFk.Id = headerTelegramaViewModel.TaBarHeader.Id;
            _unitofwork.BarHeader.Add(taBarBody.BarHeaderFk);

            taBarBody.BarTelegramaFk = new TaBarTelegrama();
            taBarBody.BarTelegramaFk.NrTg = bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarTelegrama.NrTg;
            taBarBody.BarTelegramaFk.Continut1Tg = bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarTelegrama.Continut1Tg;
            _unitofwork.BarTelegrama.Add(taBarBody.BarTelegramaFk);

            taBarBody.Codstatie1 = bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.Codstatie1;
            _unitofwork.BarBody.Add(taBarBody);
            _unitofwork.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I'm trying to pass the headerTelegramaViewModel.TaBarHeader.Id from Details in this Create method so I can create TaBarBodies in that particular TaBarHeader_Id but I receive the following error:

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>
> TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel.TaBarHeader.get
> returned null.

How can I pass the Id from TaBarHeader to the Create method in order to create TaBarBodies with a particular TaBarHeader_Id?

**Update**: Here are the requested models and viewmodels:

```
public partial class TaBarHeader
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string ListaOtf { get; set; }
        public string NomCategoriaId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NomCategoriaId")]
        public TaNomCategoria CategoriaFk { get; set; }
        public string NomCauzaId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NomCauzaId")]
        public TaNomCauza CauzaFk { get; set; }
        public List<TaBarBody> TaBarBodies { get; set; }
}

    public partial class TaBarBody
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string NomImpactId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NomImpactId")]
        public TaNomImpact ImpactFk { get; set; }
        public string NomAnulatId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NomAnulatId")]
        public TaNomAnulat AnulatFk { get; set; }
        public int BarTelegramaId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BarTelegramaId")]
        public TaBarTelegrama BarTelegramaFk { get; set; }
        public int BarHeaderId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BarHeaderId")]
        public TaBarHeader BarHeaderFk { get; set; }
}

public class HeaderTelegramaViewModel
{
    public TaBarHeader TaBarHeader { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarHeader> taBarHeader { get; set; }
    public TaBarBody TaBarBody { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarBody> taBarBody { get; set; }
}

public class BodyTelegramaViewModel
{
    public TaBarBody TaBarBody { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarBody> taBarBody { get; set; }
    public TaBarTelegrama TaBarTelegrama { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarTelegrama> taBarTelegrama { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What calls your create method? Is it a button in your cshtml page? If so, I think that will need to be within a form whose 'action' will be the route to your controller and method, and result in the data posting to your Create method.

Comment: Can you post your models pls. Hard to understand what are you looking for

Comment: @MattB , I have changed in `Details.cshtml` the line `<a asp-controller="BodyTelegrama" asp-action="Create" asp-route-id="@Model.TaBarHeader.TaBarBodies">Create new Telegram</a>` to `<a asp-controller="BodyTelegrama" asp-action="Create" asp-route-id="@Model.TaBarHeader.Id">Create new Telegram</a>` but when the Create method is called I get an error that ClasaFk from TaBarHeader cannot be null.

Comment: @Serge , I have added them to the original post.

Comment: @Homeboy53 ah OK so now you're passing in a single parameter via your asp-route-id, which is an Int. Your Create method in your controller is expecting a HeaderTelegramaViewModel and a BodyTelegramaViewModel, so if you change this method signature to expect a single int (your headerId), does that work?